# Prototype Cells in a nib instead of a storyboard

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, nib, uistoryboard

For better re-usability I want to create a table view outside of my Storyboard.

Now when I create a `UITableView` based ViewController with Nib in Xcode I get the default TableView in the nib file. However, I am not able in Interface Builder to add prototype cells like I am in my Storyboard.

Is it currently not possible to add prototype cells in a nib or am I missing something.

Thanks very much for any help.

Comment: In addition to correct answer above I would refer to great detailed solution for this case. - [Link to StackAnswer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10298648/1698467) (by using `UITableView: registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:` and `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` with `.xib` files)

Comment: This question/answer is a bit confusing to me. I came here looking for a way to use prototype cells within a table view when defining a table view in a xib. It's perfectly possible in a storyboard yes, but somehow within a xib there just is no such feature.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

iOS 5 includes a new method on UITableView: [registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:)

To use it, put a UITableViewCell in a nib. It has to be the only root object in the nib.

You can register the nib after loading your tableView, then when you call dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: with the cell identifier, it will pull it from the nib, just like if you had used a Storyboard prototype cell.

Comment: Fantastic - I was just wondering how to do this, searched here, saw your answer, then saw that mine (which turns out to be wrong!) was the accepted answer. Besi, you should accept this one instead.

Comment: Is there any way to set the file owner of these cells to be the controller where they are registered from?

Comment: Thanks for this solution. This is probably the best way for reusable tableview cells for storyboards I have come across so far.

Comment: It's very useful! I'm so glad having this method solve same problem.

Comment: The only downside is you have to wire up all the action selectors yourself, which I'm just doing by calling addTarget during willDisplayCell and then calling removeTarget during the cell's prepareForReuse method. Is there something more clever I could be doing, that would let you wire things in storyboard?

Comment: Thanks for mentioning this: "It has to be the only root object in the nib." I was trying to combine my tableviewcell and view nibs together but couldn't find any info about how `UINib` would find my tableviewcell. That settled it!

Comment: Can I ask - what if you don't want to use a custom .nib ?  Supposing I just want basic UITableViewCells with a textLabel.  What reuseIdentifier name should I specify in the "cellForRowAtIndexPath" function ?   Unlike UITableViews in a Storyboard, there is nowhere for me to define the reuseIdentifier, when the UITableViewController is in it's own .xib file..

Comment: @MikeGledhill you can define the reuse identifier in a xib the exact same way as in a Storyboard file.

Comment: Link doesn't work any more, here's an updated one: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:

Answer (score 7):

**In Swift 4:**

1. Create new CocoaTouch Class, Subclass from UITableViewCell.
2. **Important** - Enable the checkbox **'Also create XIB file'** which creates a Swift file and a .xib file
3. Add labels in the Xib, as you would do for a prototype cell in Storyboard
4. Connect label outlets to the new swift file
5. **Important** - **Register** the nib file in viewDidLoad

   ```
   yourTableview.register(UINib.init(nibName: "CustomCellTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
   ```

   (or)

   ```
   yourTableview.register(UINib(nibName: "CustomCellTableViewCell", bundle: Bundle.main), forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
   ```
6. Implement the datasource and delegates as normal and typecaste to the CustomCell in cellForRowAtIndexPath.