# Random UI updating with custom UITableViewController and Prototype cells defined from Storyboard

Tags: ios, user-interface, uitableview

I have created a subclass of `UITableViewController` that is used as the custom class for a View in my storyboard. The view has a number of sections/rows defined as prototype cells which are instantiated and shown as expected. Most of the `UITableView` delegate methods simply call the super's methods that handle section amount, rows, etc.

I have cached content that is used to update the cells on `-viewDidLoad` and then an asynchronous operation that reloads the content from my server and rebinds the data afterwards (on the main thread, `-performSelectorOnMainThread:`:). It is at this point that, seemingly arbitrarily, some of the cells content (labels primarily) will be cleared of data and not updated to the new data for anywhere between 10-15 seconds. At which point either the content which just show up or sometimes scrolling in the table view will cause the content to appear.

I know the selector is being called and on the main thread, the UI element's text properties are getting set but randomly they just...don't update. I've tried adding in `-setNeedsDisplay` on the tableView, controller's view and `-reloadData` on the tableView (though the last one seemed unnecessary as they're prototype cells) all to no avail.

Anyone come across this?

Comment: I found a "questionable" fix - changing my UILabels to UITextFields fixed it. I haven't posted this as the fix because I'm still trying to find out WHY the UILabels aren't updated similarly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My comment did indeed fix my problem. It seems `UILabel`'s are not updated when modified but rather it's decided internally when to repaint them - regardless if you try to force it with `display` or setNeedsDisplay.

Solution: Use a `UITextView` instead of a `UILabel`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is caused by the thread aspects, or how the tableView is handled. If it is tableView, check out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574188/prototype-cells-in-a-nib-instead-of-a-storyboard) since there are some similarity to disappearing data that my app was experiencing until I handled the dynamic, prototype tvCells correctly.