# iOS5 Storyboard: Reuse Custom UITableViewCell in multiple UITableViewControllers

Tags: ios5, storyboard, uitableview

Using a dynamic, custom cell prototype that I design in, say, **UITableViewController A** (in Interface Builder/Storyboard), works really well with dequeuing the cell (through its identifier, **cellA**) and such in cellForRow... I use a custom class (UITableViewCell subclass, let's name it **MyCustomCell**) to link up the labels and image thumb and it works all pretty well and straight forward in my **UITableViewController A**.

Now I create a **UITableViewController B** (in Storyboard), which happens to have the exact same design/functionality for its custom cells (dynamic cells). So I switch the class of these cells to the **MyCustomCell** and give it a new identifier, **cellB**.

In **UITableViewController B**, I dequeue the cell in cellForRow... and use the new identifier **cellB**. Note: Using **cellA** here leads to a crash, more or less obviously.

But when the table view shows up, while running the app, the **UITableViewController A** works just fine, and the almost identical **UITableViewController B** does not work (empty cells).

In Storyboard, it looks sort of off a bit, because the custom cell is designable within the **UITableViewController A** but in **UITableViewController B**, it's just a simple, plain cell. Despite the class associated to **MyCustomCell**.

How would one avoid copy&pasting these cells to the other controller (and therefore heavily going back and forth between copies when making design changes) – and rather just properly re-use it?

Comment: A good question, exactly what I have been wondering. And if I add a new subclass of UITableViewCell, the option to create a XIB for it is greyed out.

Comment: I think this is answered pretty well in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245969/in-a-storyboard-how-to-make-a-custom-cell-for-use-with-multiple-controllers

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is correct. I don't know why its not working, it may be some problem with reloading the tableview; check with your datasource and the datasource method.

```
- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *) tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger) section
```

rather what you can do is: drag a

> Viewcontroller

and then drag a

> tableview

and make it dynamic and do the thing that you did earlier; it worked fine for me when I did so myself.

Answer (score 1):

Saying the Cell is from a your custom class doesn't mean it's "designed" the same. What you really try to achieve here (and what I'm looking for) is some king of "Contained" Cell, but this is only doable with a ContainerViewController in iOS 6 I think. The other option is to use a XIB for that one Cell — that should work just as good, but then you lose the benefits of having an overview in the Storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, I had created a custom cell with a uitextfield inside it. It was working well in the first tableview but not in the second. I figured out that the textfield's delegate was not connected to the custom cell. I connected the two in storyboard by making a connection from textfields delegate outlet back to the textfield.

Comment: Correct. Just drag it from the second VC/TV... of course a duplicate named variable will be created; but that's OK. You can comment it out (or delete it). Then the xib/storyboards are hooked up for the same custom UITableViewCell to be used in more than on UITableView.