# How reuse UITableViewCell view which is created in Storyboard in different UItableViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mobile, uitableview, storyboard

Hi I created UITableViewCell in **ControllerA** in Storyboard. I need use the same UITableViewcell in different **ControllerB**. I need achive this only with storyboard. 
Any idea how can I make it?

Comment: Here is already a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245969/in-a-storyboard-how-to-make-a-custom-cell-for-use-with-multiple-controllers

Comment: You need to create an .xib file (In XCode 6 you can just copy paste contents of tableview cell after creating new xib file)

Answer (score 1):

you can use this like bellow :-

in story board you have to put another Table-cell into ControllerB nib and give it class name that you want to similar custom cell like bellow:-

[image]

and

[image]

and your ControllerB 's `cellForRowAtIndexPath` look like this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    Members_Cell *cell  = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Members_Cell"];

    cell.lblMemberName.text=[ArrSearchResult objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return  cell;

}
```

Comment: check properly this is working method that i used in my project i think you forget to set custome class of tableview's cell from story board at secondviewcontroller xib

Comment: I need set custom class in ControllerA and ControllerB with the same identifier?