# How to convert xib based project to Storyboard based project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard, xib

I've a project which is created with xib files.
Now I want to fully migrate the project to Storyboard.
Should I create a new project with Universal Storyboards in the new project and copy the rest of the code,
OR
Is it fine to create a storyboards(for iphone and ipad) in the current xib based project ?
Suggestion please.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, both are a viable option. I, personally, would go for the making a new project and copying over the files route, just because I feel like it would be the most simple. (but of course that's just my opinion) In all likelihood there will be some code you'll have to change, but you'll mostly just have to focus on the storyboard aspect of it. It shouldn't, in theory, be too difficult to get the hang of storyboards, but even so there are some pretty good tutorials out there that could help.

Answer (score 0):

Don't feel compelled to use only XIB or only Storyboards. XIB's can still be a viable solution to many problems. Also, don't feel compelled to put all your screens in the same storyboard. It is a bad idea even if it's what most people do.

More to your question, it is fine to start creating storyboards in your current project.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely go ahead and create views for each of your view controllers all in a single new story board in your current project but the issue you will face is : How to create the view for a single cell of a Table View or UICollectionView.So basically we cannot hookup everything in storyboards right now. However a mix approach of using storyboard for major view controllers and xib files for rest of the views/cells can be taken.

To look at a broader aspect of this comparison read this: [Storyboard for multiple controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245969/in-a-storyboard-how-to-make-a-custom-cell-for-use-with-multiple-controllers)