# UIStoryboard define a collectionViewCell and reuse it

Tags: ios, uicollectionviewcell

I defined a `UICollectionViewCell` in `UIStoryboard`, which I want to use in multiple `UIViewControllers`.

Is there any way, that changes to the cell in the storyboard are propagated to all the other instances? Back in the day it was possible to also put a UIView (or in this case `UICollectionViewCell`) into a xib-file and directly instantiate that, but with storyboard I can't figure it out. Is this possible?

The `UICollectionViewCell` is subclassed, but the layout is defined in the storyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although your question is specifically for a UICollectionViewCell, I am sure that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245969/in-a-storyboard-how-to-make-a-custom-cell-for-use-with-multiple-controllers) (Which is for a UITableViewCell) is general enough, so as to solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the referral. Although it does not really solve my problem, there just seems to be no way for this at the current time. Thx!