# Same UICollectionViewCell and UITableViewCell in several tables / collectionViews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionviewcell, xcode7

There are advantages to designing a cell (in a table view or collection view) inside the table/collection, within a storyboard: You get to see the design in context, and you don't have to register the cell in code.

However, it breaks down a bit if you use the same cell in different tables / collection views.

As far as I can see, you have to have copies of the cell design in each table view. This is not very DRY.

I could always use `registerNib` with a separate xib for the cell, but this removes it from the storyboard.

What is the best practice for doing this? Is there a way to have a reference to a separate cell xib in the storyboard so I can see in in context?

Comment: I use the registerNib approach when I want to share them and then in the storyboard when they are unique. I've never found a way to share them across stoyboards

Comment: Please take a look into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245969/in-a-storyboard-how-do-i-make-a-custom-cell-for-use-with-multiple-controllers, it may be useful

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with storyboard too. Set the custom class for UITableViewCell. You can use the same for multiple tableview.