# Having multiple instances of a subclass in Swift

Tags: swift

I've subclassed a `UICollectionViewCell` in which there is a `UIImageView`. This image view is connected to an image view control on the story board. This is the subclass:

```
class ProfilesCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var ProfileImage: UIImageView!

    func setCell(item:Profile) {
        ProfileImage.image = UIImage(named: item.profileThumb)
        ProfileImage.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
        ProfileImage.layer.borderColor = UIColor.grayColor().CGColor
    }
}
```

I've created an instance of it and it works fine, but what about another instance? how can I choose it as a custom class for another `UICollectionViewCell` without reconnecting the `ProfileImage` to another control?

Or shall I connect that `IBOutlet` to the `UIImageView` at the first place?

Storyboard:
[image]

Comment: can you clarify what your question is?  Are you trying to re-use one imageview across multiple colelctionVIews?  or do you want different images in each view?

Comment: @bolan I want to reuse it across multiple collectionviews

Comment: then how your doing it is ok  If you have hooked up your prototype cell to the tableview properly, it will use that cell instead of UIColelctionViewCell.  and it will reference profileImage as a UIImageView.  Make sure on the storyboard you have overwriten the class name as your CustomClass name

Comment: might want to post some storyboard pics if you're unsure if you did it correctly

Comment: @bolnad as you can see, `UIImageView` in the `MalesCV` is connected to the `ProfilesCell`, I have another collectionview just like `MalesCV` and want to use it with this subclass.

Comment: if you want to use the CollectionViewCell across multiple collectionviews, then you should make a separate .xib file and load it into each collectionview that you want to re-use it.

Comment: Write it in a new answer then i can mark it as the answer.@bolnad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a UICollectionViewCell across multiple UICollectionView, you should create the UICollectionViewCell in a separate .xib.  In this case you will have ProfileCell.xib, and ProfileCell.swift.  In the .xib file you drag an instance of a UICollectionViewCell onto the screen and set it up the way you would as a prototype cell on a CollectionView.

[image: UICollectionViewCell on xib]

Then you will need to register the cell with your collectionview.

```
    //set this up in viewDidLoad
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "ProfileCell", bundle: nil)
    self.collectionView!.registerNib(nib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "ProfileCell")
```

Then in cellForItemAtIndexPath just reference the cell in the normal way

```
 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    cell =    self.collectionView?.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("ProfileCell, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ProfileCell
    cell.setCell()
    return cell
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

> This image view [from the cell] is connected to an image view control on the story board.

I assume that you are talking about a `UICollectionViewCell` *prototype*. In this case, the object that you manipulate in the story board is not *the* collection view cell, it's a *prototype* of all image view cells in your `UIImageView`.

> I've created an instance of it and it works fine, but what about another instance?

This is precisely the scenario the designers of Swift had in mind, so everything should work the way you expect. When you call `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:` method, Cocoa instantiates the cell for you, "wires up" your `ProfileImage` to its `UIImageView` outlet, and gives you a cell that is ready for use.

Comment: When I use this subclass for the second collectionview, I face this error: ```fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value```

Comment: @Maysam Did you add your cell to Xcode as a prototype cell? [Use this walk-through for an example](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_7_Storyboard-based_Collection_View_Tutorial#Adding_the_Collection_View_Cell_Class_to_the_Project).

Comment: Yes I did, check the storyboard picture. If I remove the second collectionview everything works.

Comment: @Maysam I didn't see the update about multiple collection views reusing the same class. See [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9245969/335858), answer #2, for information on how this can be done. The Q&A talks about `UITableViewCell` objects, but it is easy to adapt to collection view cells.