# Making a single Prototype UITableCell for use with multiple controllers

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

This post explains why a single Storyboard prototype UITableCell cannot be used for multiple Views:

[In a storyboard, how do I make a custom cell for use with multiple controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245969/in-a-storyboard-how-do-i-make-a-custom-cell-for-use-with-multiple-controllers/9246873#9246873)

However, that was for Objective-C in 2012. Is it still true now for Swift, and if not how is it achieved please? Thank you.

Comment: *However, that was for Objective-C in 2012. Is it still true now for Swift* Before asking this question, I wish you should have given a try. Why you think that it will only work in Obj C and not work for Swift ?

Comment: @MidhunMP the previous question was for Obj-C, this is for Swift, which is built completely new from the ground up, so it is actually a new question.

Comment: Swift and Objective C, two different language for doing same thing. Both supports same frameworks. So there is no importance for language here. Only question valid here is "How to create a single Prototype UITableCell for using in multiple tableview". That thing is already answered in the linked question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is still true. It's in a limitation of the application frameworks, not of the language. That said, it is possible to register a nib  file that defines a cell and share it across multiple view controllers

Comment: Thank you @DuncanC. Perhaps you could teach Midhun-MP to be a bit more gracious too?