# dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier not returning cell of my custom type

Tags: iphone, ios5, uitableview, storyboard

I am using ios5 storyboards with a UITableViewController with a UITableViewCell subclass.  I do not want to design the visual elements of the cell in the storyboard designer for the view, because I want to use a reusable subclass of UITableViewCell (specifically [TDBadgedCell](https://github.com/tmdvs/TDBadgedCell)).

I have set my cell identifier in the storyboard designer, and all of the rows load correctly in the UITableView as long as I'm not setting any of the properties unique to TDBadgedCell.  If I set the `badgeString` property though which is unique to TDBadgedCell, I get an exception.  I narrowed down that `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` is not returning a cell of type TDBadgedCell.

I'm only running into this with a UITableViewController.  I have a UIViewController with an embedded UITableView set up in the same fashion and it's not an issue.  Any ideas?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"PhoneNumberCell";
TDBadgedCell *cell = (TDBadgedCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[TDBadgedCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

if ([cell isKindOfClass:[TDBadgedCell class]])
{
    NSLog(@"It is TDBadgedCell");
}
else
    NSLog(@"It is NOT TDBadgedCell");
```

Comment: did u also change the "Custom Class" to be TDBadgedCell in storyboard designer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prototype Cells in a nib instead of a storyboard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574188/prototype-cells-in-a-nib-instead-of-a-storyboard) - only possible, I'm not sure if you have a separate xib for this cell or not.

Comment: June1st - That was it!  Thanks!  I'm not sure how to mark your answer as the answer though.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in that I am subclassing UITableViewCell but not using storyboard.  Here is my solution to using different cell classes dependent on if the user had purchase the unlock feature of the app.  Hope it helps someone.

In a nutshell, I had the cell with several objects including a UITextView object.  I wanted to lock down the copy and paste feature of the UITextView object in the lite version but then release the feature once the user had purchased in in-app product.

I had two UITableViewCell classes, one with UITextView as it is and another with UITextView subclassed with canBecomeFirstresponder returning NO.  That way the user could still scroll up and down the UITextview data but not copy and paste the data.

Here is the code and all I had to do was rename the reuse identifiers.

WHY?  Because [self.tableview reloadData] would not rebuild the cells with the new class as the cell was still in existence.  New cells off the screen would get the new class but existing ones would not.  This solution rebuilds all cells once off after the purchase unlocking the added feature.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


if (your test if in-app was purchased is yes)
{
static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyCell";

FrontCell *cell = (FrontCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

if (cell == nil)
        {
        cell = [[FrontCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        cell.shouldIndentWhileEditing = NO;
    }

//....///     

cell.trackDetails.text = [yourObject objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.trackDetails.delegate = self;
cell.trackDetails.tag = indexPath.row;


return cell;
}
else // inapp not purchased
{
    static NSString *MyLockedIdentifier = @"MyLockedCell";

    FrontCellLocked *cell = (FrontCellLocked *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyLockedIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[FrontCellLocked alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MyLockedIdentifier];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        cell.shouldIndentWhileEditing = NO;
    }

     //....///     

cell.trackDetails.text = [yourObject objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.trackDetails.delegate = self;
cell.trackDetails.tag = indexPath.row;


return cell;    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In storyboard,you can set the Custom Class property for a subclass of UITablviewCell.
Then dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier method will return cell with the type of your subclass.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using wrong method for dequeuing the cells.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tblProfileInfo dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"PostCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    return cell;

}
```

You forgot for indexPath at the end.

Comment: Try changing "TDBadgedCell *cell = (TDBadgedCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];" to
"TDBadgedCell *cell = (TDBadgedCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];"