# Why there is no prototypeCell in View.xib?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uistoryboard, xib

When we add any UITableView to UIViewController through storyboard we will see screen like this

[image]

and there is an option for PrototypeCell top right side. But when we add the UITableView to View.xib we will see screen like this

[image]

and here there is no PrototypeCell. I am not understanding this why there is difference. Please explain.

Comment: this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574188/prototype-cells-in-a-nib-instead-of-a-storyboard

Answer (score 0):

It's different because when you drag and drop a `UItbaleViewController` in the `UIStoryboard`, it assume that you will use `dynamic cells`, and when you drag and dropped a simple `UITableView` it changed the property to static, which means that you will provide different UI and informations to each cells.

You can change the style to `dynamic` instead of `plain` if you want to have `prototype cells`.

Answer (score 0):

PrototypeCell not available in xib file, storyboard only.

You can use separated xib for UITableViewCell in this case. (in storyboard case you also can use separated xib for cells)