# include XIB file in tableview cell SWIFT

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2, xib

I have created the xib file(**CustomView**) with a image view and label. the class named **CustomView.swift** and it has the outlets. what i need is to use the xib in cell instead of designing in the cell itself. if it is possible then how to use the outlets from the **CustomView.swift** to **SecondTableViewController.swift**

my **CustomView.swift**

```
class CustomView: UITableViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var CImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var CLabel1: UILabel!
/*
}
```

**SecondTableViewController.swift**

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "CustomView", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")as! CustomView
    return cell
}
```

shows error[error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSciv.png)

[after cell edit image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVut7.png)

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/540345/how-do-you-load-custom-uitableviewcells-from-xib-files

Comment: I think this is answer for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574188/prototype-cells-in-a-nib-instead-of-a-storyboard

Comment: yes @Ollie but for Swift this is not working

Comment: Can you post your code for the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method? That would help find what's going wrong

Comment: @Ollie i have updated the code

Comment: Great, can you try moving the second line `tableView.registerNib...` to the `viewDidLoad` of your `UITableViewController`? Also the first line, you're casting the cell to a `UITableViewCell`, where actually it should be casted to your `CustomView`

Comment: @Ollie lldb error occurs i have added the screen and code as wt u said.

Comment: We're getting there, you've changed your cell identifier in the line `tableView.dequeueResuableCell...` though. Change that back to 'Cell' and give it a try

Comment: Ok, I've just implemented it and it is, so first question. Is your xib file also called "CustomView"? Second question, are you still getting the same error message?

Comment: xib and class is same name **CustomView** and error is uncaught exception

Comment: Could you update the error screen image with the latest code and error?

Comment: @Ollie 2nd screen code added

Comment: Ok you haven't hooked up your `IBOutlet` on your xib file to the `CustomView.swift` file

Comment: @Ollie i have created by drag and drop only

Comment: So does your connections inspector within Xcode look very similar to this? http://i.imgur.com/Q46Ol3P.png

Comment: @Ollie yes it looks the same

Comment: I've run out of ideas I'm afraid, that exception means something is not hooked up correctly, so if that's not the case then I'm not sure. This is my project which uses your code and works, check through it and see if anything is different I suppose. http://we.tl/i5rFHMJmcX Sorry I couldn't be more help!

Comment: @Ollie how to set the label value from tableview controller

Comment: Inside `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath`, just call `cell.CLabel1.text = "Your text here"`

Comment: I have one more doubt@Ollie in main storyboard we didnt specified reuse identifier name as "Cell" but it Works how.

Comment: You specified the reuse identifier in `ViewDidLoad`, so you didn't need to specify is twice.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ollie for ur help i got some idea about this concept. thanks