# IOS blank start screen

Tags: ios

I created a controller called Login with the xib file. I'm wanna make it the start screen. so in my app delegate,

H file:

```
UIWindow *login;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *login;
```

M file:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
[self.login makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

am I missing anything like linking to interface builder? am getting a blank screen

Comment: do you have a view? a window without a view is black..

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create a `UIViewController` subclass together with your login nib file and then `alloc` and `init` this view controller so that you can then make the `UIViewController`'s view the main view.

Even better would probably be the use of storyboard, where you can easily set the initial view controller all on your storyboard.

There is a good [Tutorial about iOS Storyboards](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1). I personally find the use of storyboards very convenient. In this SO question I listed some of the pros and cons of storyboards (IMHO):

[Does storyboard eliminate the need for .nib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495179/does-storyboard-eliminate-the-need-for-nib/8574345#8574345)